# How to Improve data loading when field name is stored in a table

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, dynamic-sql

I need to make the following code efficient (speed -up). It is extremely slow.
I am updating and inserting into multiple tables and the field names to update are stored in a temp table with the layout below:

- variablename
- valueforvariablename
- foreign_key1
- foreign_key2
- databasetable_name

Code:

```
DECLARE

  TYPE t_char_array IS TABLE OF VARCHAR2(32) INDEX BY BINARY_INTEGER;
  t_cursor SYS_REFCURSOR;
  t_id t_char_array;
  t_varnm t_char_array;
  t_valuex t_char_array;
  t_fpk1 t_num_array;
  t_dbtable t_char_array;
  t_fpk2 t_num_array;
  t_row_count NUMBER :=0;
  sql_stmt VARCHAR2(700);
  sql_cursor VARCHAR2(300);
  sql_inserr VARCHAR2(100);

   BEGIN
      sql_cursor :='SELECT id, varnm, valuex,fpk1,dbtable, fpk2 FROM '||&tableq;

     OPEN t_cursor for sql_cursor;
        LOOP
           FETCH t_cursor
               BULK COLLECT INTO t_id, t_varnm, t_valuex, t_fpk1, t_dbtable,t_fpk2

     LIMIT 1000;
     EXIT WHEN t_row_count = t_cursor%ROWCOUNT;
     t_row_count := t_cursor%ROWCOUNT;

     FOR i IN 1..t_id.count loop
         if t_dbtable(i) =' Temp_table' then
            sql_stmt:='UPDATE Temp_table SET '||t_varnm(i)||' =:1
                  WHERE pk = '||t_fpk1(i)||' and dictionary_pk = '||t_fpk2(i) ;

            if t_vartype(i) ='D' then 
                 EXECUTE IMMEDIATE sql_stmt using to_date(t_valuex(i),'YYYYMMDD');
            else
                 EXECUTE IMMEDIATE sql_stmt using (t_valuex(i));
            end if; 

            if sql%rowcount = 0 then
                 sql_stmt:='insert into Temp_table (pk, fpk2,'||t_varnm(i)||' )
                         VALUES (seq_steps.nextval,t_fpk2(i),t_valuex(i))';
            end if;          

        end if;
     end loop;
         exit when t_id.count < 1000; 
  end loop;
commit;
```

Answer (score 2):

Combine multiple INSERTs and UPDATEs into a smaller number of MERGEs.  This approach will read from the input table more times but may significantly reduce the amount of dynamic SQL.  This is actually *more* logical work but it may perform much better because it cuts down on the switches between SQL and PL/SQL.

```
begin
    for merges in
    (
        select distinct id, varnm, vartype
        from &tableq
        where dbtable = ' Temp_table'
    ) loop
        execute immediate '
            merge into temp_table
            using
            (
                select fpk1, fpk2,
                    '||case when mergest.vartype = 'D' then
                        'to_date(valuex, ''YYYYMMDD'')'
                    else 'valuex' end||'
                from &tableq
                where varnm = :merges_varnm
                    and vartype = :merges_vartype
            ) new_data
            on
            (
                temp_table.pk = new_data.fpk1
                and
                temp_table.dictionary_pk = new_data.fpk2
            )
            when matched then update set
                '||merges.varnm||' = new_data.valuex
            when not matched then insert(pk, fpk2, '||merges.varnm||')
                values(seq_steps.nextval, new_data.fpk2, valuex)
        ' using merges.varnm, merges.vartype;
    end loop;
end;
/
```

Comment: Thanks for your import. I tried that approach and it perform little worse then the one above. What is also confusing I am testing this with only 11k records but it is taking over 46 mins to load the data. Is there a way to use forall in my case?